# Flutter: Display text with embedded html tags and make the email and phone number clickable

Tags: flutter

How do I display text with embedded html tags and then make the email and phone number clickable in Flutter?

Example text:

```
Good to know you!<br/><br/> <br/>Apply online today! If you have any questions please contact fname@lname@company.com<br/>theUser will reach out if we believe you would be a good fit.<br/><br/>
<br>111-222-3333</br>
```

I want to make the phone and email in the text clickable and open the correct app (email or phone).

Here my code snippet to display the text:

```
 Container(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
   child: Html(
     defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
     data: jobDetail.description,
 ),
```

I am using the plugin "flutter_html 0.11.0" to render the text.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the anchor tag with `tel:` and `mailto:` href prefixes. An email link may even be able to prefill some fields.

```
<a href="tel:3177594940">317.759.4940</a> 
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```